# Changing tintColor to default (blue) in NavBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, tintcolor

I can change the tintColor for my App (everywhere) in a setting pane.
When I change the tintColor, and after that try to return to the default tint color, some buttons in NavBar don't return to blue, how can I handle this?

To verify:
- create a new project Master/Detail
- In the detail view: add Two buttons, named: "Red Interface" and "Blue interface"
- In DetailViewController, add the actions

```
@IBAction func tapRed(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.window!.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
}


@IBAction func tapBlue(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.window!.tintColor = nil
}
```

Now run the application, create a timestamp, go to detail, tap redInterface, then blue interface
That's OK in the Detail View, but when you return to Master, the "+" button item is red, not blue.

I can fix the problem by setting a real blue color instead of nil, but that's not a long term solution, if Apple change the default tintColor.

Is this a bug? Is there something I can do to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround would be to fetch the default tint color once on the initial app load and store it somewhere (i.e. in the user defaults)

From Apple's  [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1) (Specifically under the *Using Tint Color* section).

> By default, a view’s tint color is nil, which means that the view uses its parent’s tint. It also means that when you ask a view for its tint color, it always returns a color value, even if you haven’t set one.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good workaround!

In fact, I don't even need to store the color.
If I change to

```
    @IBAction func tapBlue(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.window!.tintColor = UIButton(type:UIButtonType.System).titleColorForState(.Normal)
}
```

That gives me the correct blue color, even if I changed the tintColor (probably because I don't address a button in the view hierarchy)